# Does somebody knows this european bird that i saw close to a river in an open grasland?

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

I saw today afternoon (10. June) this bird and would like to know the species name. It was on a sunny day in the middle of the Netherlands (central Europe) in an wet meadow close to a big river. I took several picture from the same individual, but they were two birds of the same species passing quite fast close to the ground of the meadow.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm no expert or from europe , but I think common linnet, based on a very brief google image search for "finch europe". Maturing reddish head and breast, gray neck,brown wings with dark tips.

Comment: thanks for your input. I was also considering this the marks are not that clear. sure the quality of the picture is also not great. but anyway.

Comment: I think marks aren't clear because juvenile heading into adult, but as I said, no expertise on this at all, other than some search skills.